# syslinux bootloader unable to find the initrd.img for a custom bootable image made via Docker Containers

Tags: docker, boot-loader, bootable, syslinux

### Description

As a side project, I am trying to use **Hashicorp Packer** along with **Docker** to create Bootable disk Images from Docker Containers.

**Hashicorp Packer** generally takes the responsibility of bringing the docker containers up and execute tasks within them and then create filesystem tarballs or use containers to create image files etc.

#### How it works

1. I use an `ubuntu:focal` docker container
2. use this docker container and install a Kernel / Systemd On it:

   ```
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends linux-image-virtual systemd-sysv
   ```
3. Create a tarball of the container which now contains the kernel, initrd and system from step 2
4. unpack the tarball on the host machine to be able to use it when creating an image file
5. Spin up another `ubuntu` container with privileges and mount the working directory into it to create the bootable image file.

At this point I am relying on a bash script below to create an image for me:

```bash
set -e
echo "[Install APT dependencies]"
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y extlinux fdisk qemu-utils

echo "[Create disk image of 1GB]"
dd if=/dev/zero of=/os/${DISTR}.img bs=$(expr 1024 \* 1024 \* 1024) count=1

blue "[Make partition]"
sfdisk /os/${DISTR}.img < /os/config/partition.txt

echo "\n[Format partition with ext4]"
losetup -D
LOOPDEVICE=$(losetup -f)
echo -e "\n[Using ${LOOPDEVICE} loop device]"
losetup -o $(expr 512 \* 2048) ${LOOPDEVICE} /os/${DISTR}.img
mkfs.ext4 ${LOOPDEVICE}

echo "[Copy ${DISTR} directory structure to partition]"
mkdir -p /os/mnt
mount -t auto ${LOOPDEVICE} /os/mnt/
cp -R /os/${DISTR}.dir/. /os/mnt/


echo "[Setup extlinux]"
extlinux --install /os/mnt/boot/
cp /os/config/syslinux.cfg /os/mnt/boot/syslinux.cfg

echo "[Unmount]"
umount /os/mnt
losetup -D

echo_blue "[Write syslinux MBR]"
dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/os/${DISTR}.img bs=440 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

The `DISTR` in the above script is `ubuntu` and the `ubuntu.dir` is the unpacked tarball ball which is mounted into the container to be able to copy it to the mounted partition.

#### Progress

Currently I have been successful in creating such images for `ubuntu`. The repository created can be found [here](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/PockerISO)

However upon trying to boot the image using `qemu-system-x86_64`:

```bash
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=ubuntu.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw
```

I get the following error:
[image: Initrd error 1]

The respective `syslinux.cfg` for the bootloader is:

```
DEFAULT linux
  SAY Now booting the kernel from SYSLINUX...
 LABEL linux
  KERNEL /boot/vmlinuz
  INITRD /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-125-generic
  APPEND ro root=/dev/sda1
```

### Additional Changes

I tried updating the `syslinux.cfg` to

```
DEFAULT linux
  SAY Now booting the kernel from SYSLINUX...
 LABEL linux
  KERNEL /boot/vmlinuz
  APPEND ro root=/dev/sda1 initrd=/boot/initrd.img
```

however I get the same error, albeit `/boot/initrd.img` is not found is the error message.

What am I currently missing from myside to make the `initrd.img` discoverable for the bootloader.

I have tried using `cp -dR /os/ubuntu.dir/. /os/mnt` in the bash script to make sure symbolic links are preserved while copying.

I have also made sure to see if the symlink `initrd.img` file exists in the mounted partition `/os/mnt/boot` which it exists and so does the source of the symlink file e.g. `readlink -f /os/mnt/boot/initrd.img`

### Sources

[iximiuz blogpost on docker-to-bootable devices](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/from-docker-container-to-bootable-linux-disk-image/)
[PockerISO](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/PockerISO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution to the problem. It was the fact that although I was installing the linux kernel via

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends linux-image-virtual
```

It was unable to generate the `initrd` which usually happens when I let the complete recommended packages get installed.

I was able to solve this issue simply by

```
apt-get install -y linux-image-virtual
```

and I am able to create Bootable Images for Ubuntu as well as Debian